# How to assign a value for a single in a VertexPaint in 3ds Max

Tags: 3ds-max

I have a mesh and it has `VertexPaint` modifier. How I can set values on a per vertex basis?

I tried to select a single vertex and looked for any property I can change to change its coloring.

I need to export it to `fbx` format and read it from my program.

Comment: You need to explain in further detail what you are trying to do, and how you've tried to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not proficient in 3DS Max, but in searching I found these two bullets that may help you:

> - VertexPaint is automatically applied to the selected object when you
>   click <kbd>Assign Vertex Colors > Assign To Selected</kbd>. It is not available
>   directly from the **Modify panel** or **Modifiers menu**.
> - To render vertex
>   colors, assign a **Vertex Color map**

[Vertex Modifier Help](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/16/ENU/3ds-Max-Help/index.html?url=files/GUID-EADD121F-482F-4387-8D6C-0548533E4F56.htm,topicNumber=d30e272707)